# How to post videos longer than 15 minutes on Instagram?

Tags: instagram, upload

Instagram does not let me post videos longer than 15 minutes and strictly gives a 15 minute limit on videos whenever I try to upload a video. However I’ve seen other people able to post videos longer than 15 minutes. Is there any way around this to be able to post videos longer than 15 minutes?

Comment: Please add more details. How old is your account? How many followers do you have? How many content have you uploaded? What is the average rating of your  content?